# How to achieve recursive templates with jquery

Tags: jquery, templates, recursion, jquery-templates

I get a json from database, then load dynamically a template and apply that json. The data stored in this variable is self-referenced (the typical id - parent_id).
I'm unable to do a recursion of that data.

the json:

```
var my_json = {"modules":[
    {
        "id_modules": "1",
        "id_modules_parent": "0",
        "mod_name": "mod 1",
        "sub_modules": [
            {
                "id_modules": "2",
                "id_modules_parent": "1",
                "mod_name": "mod 1a",
                "sub_modules": ""
            },
            {
                "id_modules": "3",
                "id_modules_parent": "1",
                "mod_name": "mod 1b",
                "sub_modules": ""
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id_modules": "4",
        "id_modules_parent": "0",
        "mod_name": "mod 2",
        "sub_modules": [
            {
                "id_modules": "5",
                "id_modules_parent": "4",
                "mod_name": "mod 2a",
                "sub_modules": [
                    {
                        "id_modules": "7",
                        "id_modules_parent": "5",
                        "mod_name": "mod 2aa",
                        "sub_modules": ""
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id_modules": "6",
                "id_modules_parent": "4",
                "mod_name": "mod 2b",
                "sub_modules": ""
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

This is how I render the template:

```
$.get("template_file.txt", function(template)
{
    $.tmpl(template, my_json).appendTo("#some_div");
});
```

and finally the template (template_file.txt):

```
<ul class="modules_ul">
    {{each(i, module) modules}}
        <li>${module.mod_name}</li>
        {{each(j, submodule) module.sub_modules}}

            {{tmpl(submodule) ".modules_ul" }} //what goes here?

        {{/each}}
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**
added a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aNPvz/) to play around

**SOLUTION:** see mblase75's answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7272619/too-much-recursion-using-jquery-templates)

Comment: Do you have control over the JSON object? Because as long as you're using structured data, there's no reason to include parent IDs for anything.

Comment: You are right, there's no reason to include it, but the problem remains...

Comment: don't you need something to display some data, not only build a tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this

```
<ul class="modules_ul">
    {{each(i, module) modules}}
        <li>${module.mod_name}</li>
        {{if module.sub_modules}}
            {{tmpl(module.sub_modules) "template_name"}}
        {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it without a template? You'll need to create a JavaScript function that will recurse itself:

```
function recursive(modules) {
    var arr_html = new Array;
    for (var j=0; j<modules.length; j++) {
        arr_html.push("<ul>");
        arr_html.push("<li>"+modules[j].mod_name+"</li>");
        if (modules[j].sub_modules.length) // it's an array
            arr_html.push(recursive(modules[j].sub_modules));
        arr_html.push("</ul>");
    }
    return arr_html.join("");
}
$('body').append(recursive(my_json.modules));
```

Comment: Because I need to put the HTML in a separate file as it should be.

Comment: You're already mixing JavaScript and HTML by using `.tmpl()`; the only issue is how far you're going to take it. I'm not familiar with `.tmpl()` yet, but I don't see how you can include one template inside another template.

Comment: Well, if there's a template-based solution, then I'll be the second one here to employ it.

Comment: The thing is that actually there is a template-based solution but I can get it work. Is the line where I wrote "//whar goes here?"

see: [link](http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-tmpl/)

they use <script id="some_id" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"> syntax, but I load the template dynamically as a string

Comment: Here's the jQuery doc on recursive templates (scroll down a bit): http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-tmpl/

Answer (score 0):

This recursive templates works for me. There are few difference with your example: template is inline, template is accessed by id, not by class, and additional if checks is added before rendering nested template.

By the way, what kind of error do you get? Is template is not rendered at all?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data =
    {
        name: "Root",
        children:
        [
            { name: "Child1",
                children:
                [{ name: "SubChild1"}]
            },
            {
                name: "Child2",
                children:
                [{ name: "SubChild2"}]
            }
        ]
    };

    $(function () {
        $("#template").tmpl(data).appendTo("#target");

    });
</script>
<script type="text/html" id="template">
<div id="template">
    <h3>
        ${name}</h3>
    <div style="position:relative; margin-left:10px">
        {{if children}} 
            {{each(i, child) children}} 
                {{tmpl(child) "#template" }}
            {{/each}}
        {{/if}}
    </div>
</div>
</script>
<div id="target">
</div>
```

Comment: hey! can you create a working jsfidle?  
The error I'm getting is: "c.tmpl is not a function"